# MySQL search multiple tables and in one table search multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I built a query for searching one value across multiple tables. It works great as is, but I want to search multiple fields in the "customers" table ("last_name" and "company_name" additionally).

```
$sql = "SELECT first_name as name FROM customers WHERE first_name LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'
        UNION
        SELECT name as name FROM events WHERE name LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'
        UNION
        SELECT product_name as name FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'";
```

Do I just add more separate lines for each additional field like so?

```
"SELECT first_name as name FROM customers WHERE first_name LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'
    UNION
SELECT last_name as name FROM customers WHERE last_name LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'
    UNION
SELECT company_name as name FROM customers WHERE company_name LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'
```

It doesn't seem the most efficient, so wanted to check. Thanks!

Comment: If you need only 1 column as result then this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There is an efficient solution. Since you collect only name, you collect them into three different variable. and using backend language, you merge these 3 array.

```
    example for php, 
    $sql1 = "SELECT first_name as name FROM customers WHERE first_name LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'; 
    //getting first array result by this query
    $sql2 = "SELECT name as name FROM events WHERE name LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'";
    //getting second array result by this query
    $sql3 = "SELECT product_name as name FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'"; 
    //getting third array result by this query

    $result = array_merge($sql1, $sql2, $sql3)
```

This solution will be applicable, if you can manage data by your backend language.